# Can I develop a PDO extension with c++?

Tags: php, pdo, php-extension

Can I write a PDO extension with c++ instead of c?(Windows10, PHP7.2)

This is the contents(according to official docs) that a pdo ext should cover:

```
config.m4                  # unix build script
  config.w32                 # win32 build script
  CREDITS
  package.xml                # meta information about the package
  pdo_SKEL.c                 # standard PHP extension glue
  php_pdo_SKEL.h
  php_pdo_SKEL_int.h         # driver private header
  SKEL_dbh.c                 # contains the implementation of the PDO driver interface
  SKEL_stmt.c                # contains the implementation of the PDO statement interface
  tests/
```

Can I just rename the `pdo_SKEL.c` to `pdo_SKEL.cpp`, and also change the c file name to cpp in config.w32.

I tried with some simple code and function, it works.
But every time when i want to register the ext to the pdo,
the compilation would not pass.

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl php_pdo_register_driver(struct pdo_driver_t *)" (?php_pdo_register_driver@@YAHPEAUpdo_driver_t@@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl zm_startup_pdo_my_mysql(int,int)" (?zm_startup_pdo_my_mysql@@YAHHH@Z)   pdo_module  C:\php\pdo_module.obj   1
```